# batch for loop with bracket in the command

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, escaping

I have a batch file with the following code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
 echo Processing %%a >>%LOG%
 dtsrun /S(local) /NNotesLoad /A"FilePath:8="%NOTESDIR%\%%a" /AClientID=%1 >>%LOG%

 echo Deleting %%a >>%LOG%
 del %%a /q
)
```

This is returning an error message of "/NNotesLoad was unexpected at this time" because the second bracket is effectively closing the FOR block.

I have to leave the (local) as the /S parameter. 
How do I escape the brackets in the dtsrun line?

EDIT: Turns out you can specify the server in dtsrun for local as .

But I would still like an answer to the escaping for the brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for escaping the brackets characters is to prefix with a caret ^

So it would read:

```
/S^(local^)
```